# SpringBoot please suggest custom Query for

Tags: spring-data-jpa

select * from ngb.subsidy where 
(effective_start_date, effective_end_date) OVERLAPS
  ('2017-08-01'::DATE, '2017-08-01'::DATE) order by effective_start_date asc

Below given query is not working

```
@Query(value="select * from ngb.security_deposit sd  where sd.consumer_no = :consumerNo and (sd.effective_start_date, sd.effective_end_date) OVERLAPS (:effectiveStartDate::DATE, :effectiveEndDate::DATE) order by sd.effective_start_date asc",nativeQuery=true)

public  List<SecurityDepositInterface> findByConsumerNoAndEffectiveStartDateAndEffectiveEndDate(@Param("consumerNo") String consumerNo, @Param("effectiveStartDate") Date effectiveStartDate, @Param("effectiveEndDate") Date effectiveEndDate);
```

showing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [effectiveStartDate] did not exist

Answer (score 1):

In your repo

```
 @Query(value="select * from ngb.subsidy where (effective_start_date, effective_end_date) OVERLAPS ('2017-08-01'::DATE, '2017-08-01'::DATE) order by effective_start_date asc",nativeQuery=true)

 List<Your Entity class> = findbyID(); // any name
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `@Param("")`  instead of use `?1`

Example

```
@Query(value="select * from table where colNO=?1 and colNO=?2",nativeQuery=true)
List<Your Entity class> = findbyID(String val1,String val2);
```